# java extracting from string

Tags: java, regex, arrays, methods, substring

I've got an array of strings similar to

```
 <div id="option1">hello</div>
 <div style="color: cyan">world</div>
```

Is there a way that I can extract the information from within the divs? I've already written something but it's not dynamic (I have to specify the length of the  bit) which is useless on my application because the content inside the array ^ is not always the same.

Hope you can understand my question, I will reply asap if you need any more information.

I am using java.

Comment: You need an HTML parser.

Comment: Chuck Norris uses regex here:)

Comment: have you tried some of the XML parsers available in java? Sax? Xerces?

Comment: @PetarMinchev, No, Chuck Norris doesn't use regexs. Data sees him coming and parses itself.

Comment: Don't dare to use regex though it sometimes happily work with HTML.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this other than using an external library ? thanks

Comment: Is your content always well-formed, as in the example given? If so, you can use the JAXP implementation that ships with J2SE. If it's like most HTML -- that is to say, it's *not* well-formed -- then you'll need a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that there will only be one set of  HTML tags, even better if you knew what tag it was, you might be able to do something like:

```
String[] html = new String[] { 
    "<div id=\"option1\">hello</div>",
    "<div style=\"color: cyan\">world</div>" };

for(String index : html){
    int firstEnd = index.firstIndexOf("/>");
    int lastBeginning = index.indexOf("<", 2); // Could become "</div>

    String contents = index.substring(firstEnd + 1, lastBeginning - 1);
    System.out.println(contents);
}
```

Please note that I haven't tested this code, nor written it in an IDE, so it may not be entirely correct but I think you can see where I am coming from. Just get the string between the closing ">" of the last tag before the information, and the opening "<" to the closing part of the previous tag...

I can also see that something like this code be modified to handle strings will multiple HTML tags with a bit of imagination...

Alternatively, and I can't believe I didn't think of this to start with, you could use something like the following. Though, again, it is limited to one HTML tag, though I'm sure you could come up with a *tag-counting* method if needed.

```
String[] html = new String[] { 
                "<div id=\"option1\">hello</div>",
                "<div style=\"color: cyan\">world</div>" };

        String tag = "div";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<" + tag + ".*?>(.*?)</" + tag + ">");
        Matcher m;

        for(String index : html){
            m = p.matcher(index);
            while(m.find()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
        }
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

A complete [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document) example:

```
List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] html = new String[] { 
    "<div id=\"option1\">hello</div>",
    "<div style=\"color: cyan\">world</div>" };
for (String el : html) {
    String text = Jsoup.parse(el).text();
    res.add(text);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
```

Note that the HTML from your example is well-formed XML and could be parsed using any XML parser, as well. You'll need an HTML-specific parser when dealing with input that is not well-formed.

Answer (score 1):

As @SLaks said, use an HTML parser. There are lots of good ones for Java. My favourite is [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Thanks, is there anyway of doing this other than using an external library ?

Comment: Not really. Java has a good XML parser "built in", but HTML is a very different beast.